# unix home directories without entries in /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, unix, directory, passwd

I am able to get both listings ( /etc/passwd and /home ) but how to script something like read line of /etc/passwd, parse home directory, then look for that in /home . If it doesn't exist, throw an error, if it does exist, move along.

/etc/passwd home dir listing for users

```
cut -d":" -f6 /etc/passwd | grep home | sort
```

user listing from /home

```
ls -1 /home | (while read line; do echo "/home/"$line; done)
```

Maybe right out output from first command to a file, then read each line into a find command and...or, test with

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
echo "directory found for user that doesn't exist"
fi
```

Now how to put it all together...

EDIT: isedev had exactly what I needed. I may have mis-worded my original message...we have been cleaning up users, but not cleaning up their /home directory. So I want to know what /home directories still exist that don't have /etc/passwd entries.

this is what worked to a T

`for name in /home/*; do
    if [ -d "$name" ]; then
        cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | egrep -q "^$name$"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "directory $name does not correspond to a valid user"
        fi
    fi
done`

from now on, we will be running

`userdel -r login`

Comment: Not totally reliable. accounts GENERALLY have their homedir in /home, but not all of them. e.g. consider the root account, which usually lives off in `/root`

Comment: @MarcB Unless the OP wants to know if there are directories under /home which do not correspond to entries in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Are you worried about directories in `/home` claimed by more than one entry in `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming you want to know if there are directories under /home which do not correspond to existing users:

```
for name in /home/*; do
    if [ -d "$name" ]; then
        cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | egrep -q "^$name$"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "directory $name does not correspond to a valid user"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Then again, this assumes you are not using a name service such as LDAP or NIS, in which case, change the line starting with `cut` to:

```
getent passwd | cut -d':' -f6 | egrep -q "^$name$"
```

Comment: +1. As a side note, you could also simplify to `for name in /home/*; do [ -d "$name" ] && cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | grep q "^$name$" || echo "directory $name does not correspond to a valid user"; done`. I would also use simple `grep`, there's no need for `egrep` here and, anyway, that's been deprecated (at least for GNU `grep`) in favor of `grep -E` for some years now.

Comment: @terdon all good points (well, except the 'deprecated' part - makes me feel old).

Comment: Tell me about it :). I've gotten into the habit of using `grep -E` though since the man page suggests it.

Comment: POSIX 2008 standardizes [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and the `-E` option; there is no longer a separate `egrep` (or `fgrep`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler they're still there on many (all?) Linux systems for backwards compatibility.

Comment: And `gets()` is still in the C library for backwards compatibility too...things get removed from standards long before they're removed from machines.

Comment: running 1000 times `cut` and `egrep` isn't the best solution for the long passwd files.

Answer (score 2):

as 1st approximation:

```
perl -F: -lane 'next if m/^#/;print "$F[5] for user $F[0] missing\n" unless(-d $F[5])' /etc/passwd
```

if you want find the differences between the `/etc/passwd` and the `/home`

```
comm <(find /home -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print|sort) <(grep -v '^#' /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f6| grep '/home' | sort)
```

in an narrow form

```
comm    <(
            find /home -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print |sort
        ) <(
            grep -v '^#' /etc/passwd  |cut -d: -f6 |grep /home |sort
        )
```

if you will use

- `comm ...` (without args as above) will show 3 colums 1.) only in /home 2.)only in /etc/passwd 3.) common
- `comm -23 ....` - will show directories what are only in the /home (and not in the `/etc/passwd`)
- `comm -13 ....` - will show dirs what are only in the /etc/passwd and not in the `/home`
- `comm -12 ....` - will show correct directories (exists in the `/etc/passwd` and the `/home` too)

I'm not sure with the `-{max|min}depth` on the AIX..

Comment: This is on AIX...perl with -E working on AIX 7.1, but not on 6.1.

Comment: @user2341048 now the perl should work (with `-lane`)

Answer (score 2):

This will report all home directories from `/etc/passwd` that should be in `/home` but aren't:

```
cut -d":" -f6 /etc/passwd | grep home | sort | 
    while read dir; do [ -e "$dir" ] || echo Missing $dir; done
```

And this one reports all that don't exist:

```
cut -d":" -f6 /etc/passwd | while read dir; do 
    [ -e "$dir" ] || echo Missing $dir
done
```